# Jmeter : Perform calculation in CSV rows and use calculated values in test

Tags: java, csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I have been trying to create Jmeter tests to perform on more realistic timings using CSV.
I have a CSV which contains a row with timing. I would like to run tests based on difference between 2 consecutive timings in repeated manner on different threads.
My CSV is something like below. I would like calculate timings like Time = Time2-Time1, Time= Time3-Time2, etc. Save all these timings in another excel.

[image]

I was trying to run BeanShell script and followed couple of articles but didn't work out.

For example : ${Test}=${__BeanShell(${__CSVRead(Test.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(Test.csv,next)}-${__CSVRead(Test.csv,1)})}

This worked for single value but not sure how to automate this for all values of CSV and how to save it in specific row.
Any help would be very very appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was something like :

- Create loop controller.
- Read two rows using CSVread function and store there difference using _Jexl2.
- Run the loop controller until EOF of the csv.
- Create a counter in this controller and use this counter for array ${variable${Index}}.
- Store previous calculated difference in another variable with array using jexl
- Run beanshell script and throw this array in the csv.
  I know it really long solution but it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider changing your code to something like:

```
def lines = new File('old.csv').readLines()

lines.eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    new File('new.csv') << line
    if (index < lines.size() - 1) {
        def currentTime = line.split(',')[1] as long
        def nextTime = lines.get(index + 1).split(',')[1] as long
        def delta = nextTime - currentTime
        new File('new.csv') << ',' << delta << System.getProperty('line.separator')
    }

}

new File('new.csv') << ',' << '0'
```

The good place for the script is [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test), if you don't want the sampler to present in the test results add `SampleResult.setIgnore()` in the beginning of the script

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks for your solution but I have found another way of doing it by using Jmeter's inbuild functions. Didn't read your solution unfortunately (But very glad for your help) :)